# Getting Javascript variable value in PHP Variable using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to store latitude and longitude values in PHP variables, but unable to do so. Here is my code. Can someone help me out here why these values are not getting stored in php variables:

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="getLocation()">
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var longt = position.coords.longitude;
        $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: { latitude : lat, longitude : longt },
   });

}
        </script>
<?php
        $var = isset($_POST['latitude']);
        $var1 = isset($_POST['longitude']);
        echo $var;
        echo $var1;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between _client-side_ code and _server-side_ code.  AJAX sends new HTTP requests.

Comment: so do I need to redirect ajax code to other php page??

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

assuming that `lat` and `longt` are getting set properly in your javascript (you could do a `console.log` check to make sure), it looks like you are setting your `$var` and `$var1` variable to the result of the `isset()` function which returns either true or false, rather than the value of `$_POST['latitude']` or `$_POST['longitude']`.  I'm assuming you might have meant:

```
if (isset($_POST["latitude"])) {
  $var = $_POST['latitude'];
}

if (isset($_POST["longitude"])) {
  $var1 = $_POST['longitude'];
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't edit this code, but the 2nd $var should be $var1, to avoid the 2nd overwriting the first

Answer (score 1):

PHP `isset()` function returns a boolean value. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), the `isset` function is used to:

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

So in your case you are storing the return value of the function to the variable. It is either `true` or `false`.

So here is the corrected code:

```
if (isset($_POST["latitude"])) {
  $var = $_POST['latitude'];
}

if (isset($_POST["longitude"])) {
  $var1 = $_POST['longitude'];
}
```